Term not recognized - PowerShell
I have a Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 file that is:
# Go to my repo
function GoToMyRepo{Set-Location "C:\Users\me\repos\myrepo"}
Set-Alias -Name myrepo -Value GoToMyRepo

# Git push with comment
function GitPush {
    $comment = $args[0]
    git add -A
    git commit -m $comment
    git push
}
Set-Alias -Name gitpush -Value GitPush

The alias myrepo works like charm, but when I enter gitpush "message" I get this error:
gitpush: The term 'gitpush' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Any cue? Thanks in advance.

PowerShell's command discovery API is largely case-insensitive, so the alias gitpush is itself gonna end up shadowing the GitPush function - simply skip Set-Alias -Name gitpush -Value GitPush and it'll work as you want
